# How do you send and receive UDP packets in Java on a multihomed machine?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a machine with VmWare installed which added two extra network interfaces.  The OS is Vista.  I have two Java applications, one which broadcasts datagrams, and one which receives those datagrams.  The problem I'm having is that unless I disable both VmWare network interfaces, the receiver can't receive the datagrams.

What is the best way to make that work without disabling the interfaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the alternate constructor for DatagramSocket:

```
DatagramSocket(int port, InetAddress laddr)
Creates a datagram socket, bound to the specified local address.
```

I'm guessing you're only specifying the port.